# Linux Mint: Normal boot after login turns screen black

Tags: linux-mint, boot, login

If I do a standard boot of Linux Mint, it goes to the Login Screen, but as soon as I login, it flashes the desktop then the entire screen switches off - including the back light. Luckily, if I boot to Recovery Mode then 'resume', Linux boots normally. The only not-normal thing is when I login from 'resume' In recovery mode, there are strange shapes that appear on the screen made up from the desktop icons and picture.

Some things which I have tried:

- Running the various options in Recovery Mode
- Re-installing mate-screensaver
- Upgrading the entire system
- Deleting Heavy Duty apps - E.g. TeamViewer
- Running `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
- Running `sudo apt-get install -f`

None of these things have worked.

I'm not sure if this is relevant but when I run 
`lspci | grep -i --color 'vga\|3d\|2d'`

The output is:
`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 (rev 0a)`

Any Ideas?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have fixed the problem. Booting with the '[nomodeset](https://linuxmint-installation-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/boot_options.html)' option fixed everything, for more details, have a look at [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132) page.