# Linux Mint freezes after login!

Tags: linux-mint

I installed Linux Mint on my laptop. After I login, the screen goes completely dark and there is no output on the screen or anything. Same thing happened with Kubuntu also. Live-USBs worked fine.

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect your internal hard disks as being faulty? Can you access them when using a Live USB?

Comment: Are you able to switch to terminal?: Ctrl+Alt+F3

Comment: @Gryu At the login screen. Yes. Not after that.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I can access them using a Live USB. My file system is basically 128G SSD for the OS and 1 TB HDD.

Comment: Before log in switch to terminal and try to install other desktop manager (budgie, xfce) and proprietary video drivers if they are available. Also you could test installing system on hdd, but be careful to not destroy your valuable data. Back up it.

Comment: Have you tried answer from here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/530066/linux-mint-normal-boot-after-login-turns-screen-black?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:
When in grub (If you can't see grub hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while booting) select the Linux Mint option and press <kbd>e</kbd>. You should see a line that says something like this:

```
linux /boot/....... quiet splash
```

Then go at the end of the line and add `nomodeset`:

```
linux /boot/....... quiet splash nomodeset
```

Boot by pressing <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.
If that fixes your problem you can then make it permanent. Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

At the beginning of the file search for:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Once again add the nomodeset option:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>y</kbd> to save and exit.
Update grub:

```
update-grub
```

If you get the error `command not found` use

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```